# How do I use multiple "one-to-many" nested attributes in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, nested-attributes, form-for

given the fact that a user has many credit cards and a credit card has many addresses, I am trying to create a form that creates a user and credit card with address all at once

relavent model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credit_cards
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit_cards
end

class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

controller code

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.credit_cards.build
end
```

view code

```
=form_for @user, :url => users_path do |u|
  =u.label :first_name, "Name"
  =u.text_field :first_name
    -u.fields_for :credit_cards do |cc|
      =cc.label :name_on_card, "Name on Card"
      =cc.text_field :name_on_card
      -cc.fields_for :address do |address|
        =address.label :address, "Address"
        =address.text_field :address1
```

So the problem I am having is that the address fields do not show up.  I tried adding `@user.credit_cards.addresses.build` to the controller but I get a `undefined method 'build' for nil` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller, you should try:

```
cc = @user.credit_cards.build
cc.adrresses.build
```

or

```
@user.credit_cards.build
@user.credit_cards.each{|cc| cc.addresses.build }
```

`@user.credit_cards.addresses.build` doesn't work because `@user.credit_cards` returns an array…

Comment: I've just corrected a mistake I made, it's  @user.credit_cards.build
@user.credit_cards.each{|cc| cc.addresses.build } and not @user.credit_cards @user.credit_cards.each{|cc| cc.addresses.build }